# Obscure 70's or 80's Cartoon

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

This was a 1970's or 1980's Cartoon. I remember two main characters, male and female.

- I believe that they were twins. They were human in appearance, but may have had slightly elven ears.

Other points;

- I seem to remember lots of mountains (or maybe desert)?
- I seem to remember them hiding behind rocks at one point to watch a *blue creature* go by.

Comment: What country did you watch it in? What language was it in? Do you remember any other details about the characters' appearance (hair/skin color?)? Was it a movie or a TV show?

Comment: [Wonder Twins](http://vignette1.wikia.nocookie.net/superfriends/images/9/97/WT2.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20090402045004)?

Comment: I kind of wonder if they saw a copy of the Abby Lou "animated film" of Elfquest. The animation was apparently extremely minimal, though.